# jquery ajax notworking when rewrirte mode (.htaccess) actived

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

My Project Contain 5 File
And I Work With WampServer

.htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f           
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1
```

master.php

```
<h1 style="background:red;text-align:center">master.php</h1>


<!--when href="gallery/23" ajax not working-->

<a href="gallery">GALLERY</a>
```

index.php :

```
<h3>index.php received request</h3>

<?php 

if (!isset($_GET['param'])){

    include('master.php');

}


if (isset($_GET['param'])){

    if ($_GET['param']=="gallery") {

        $id="14";
        include("gallery.php");

    }

}

?>
```

gallery.php :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>              
    <h1 style="background:red;text-align:center">gallery.php</h1>                   

    <script type="text/javascript">


        window.onload = function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "controller.php",
                data: {id:"<?php echo $id?>"},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.response)
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

controller.php :

```
<?php 

$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$jason_data = array ('response'=>$id.'___received from jason data successfully');
echo json_encode($jason_data);
?>
```

when in master.php a link-> href is:

```
<a href="gallery">GALLERY</a>
```

every thing is ok and ajax work well and return jason data.BUT when alink ->href is:

```
<a href="gallery/23">GALLERY</a>
```

ajax notworking

my project direct link :

http://upir.ir/931/myproject.rar

Comment: `gallery/23` is not the same as `gallery`, therefore it makes sense for it to not work because `$_GET['param']=="gallery"` will be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because using gallery/23, your "$_GET['param']" will contain "gallery/23", so your test will fail.

You should use a route PHP library to handle the ID or better, a PHP framework.